How to auto generate an access token everytime it expires?
I am trying to develop a CRM app with nodejs and amazon seller partner api.
For this I have the following method to generate an access token:
const express = require('express');
const asyncHandler = require('../middlewares/async')
const axios = require('axios');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config({
    path: './.env'
})

exports.getToken = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(`${process.env.AMZ_ENDPOINT}`, {
            'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
            'refresh_token': process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN,
            'client_id': process.env.CLIENT_ID,
            'client_secret': process.env.CLIENT_SECRET
        });
    
        const accessToken = response.data;
        console.log(accessToken);
        res.status(200).json({ accessToken });
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
});

The response type I get is the following:
{
    "accessToken": {
        "access_token": "A access token",
        "refresh_token": "A refresh token",
        "token_type": "bearer",
        "expires_in": 3600
    }
}

I have to use the access token to make requests to the different endpoints in the amazon sp api.
The thing is every hour the access token expires. Is there a way to programatically auto generate the access token everytime it expires?

That’d be what the refresh token is actually used for. Just repeat the process and get a new bearer token the same way.

@esqew Yes I know the refresh token is actually used for this, the thing is I don´t know how can I programatically use it to automatically generate the access token everytime it expires

You can create and refresh token the same way you grant access to resources with your access token, but that /refresh path will be accessible only with refresh token and return both new refresh and access token. To generate different keys you can use separate secrets.
